# Input rational numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I am trying to input a rational number in python i cant convert it to a float number for example I can input 0.5 and convert it to float but when I input 1/2 I cant convert it. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input returns a string. So you get the string "1/2" which can not be converted to float. But you can try to call eval() to it as a way of converting:

```
num = input("Give me a number")
print(eval(num) + 5)

Give me a number5/2
7.5
```

Answer (score 2):

If your rational numbers will always be in that form, you could use the `fractions` class. I assume you want a `float` object as the final product. So something like this would work:

```
import fractions
def parse_rational(string):
    try:
        return float(string)
    except ValueError:
        return float(fractions.Fraction(string))
```

Note, this will *only* work if your strings don't have extraneous whitespace, like this:

```
>>> fractions.Fraction('1/2')
Fraction(1, 2)
```

If they do, it will error:

```
>>> fractions.Fraction('1 / 2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/juan/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/fractions.py", line 137, in __new__
    raise ValueError('Invalid literal for Fraction: %r' %
ValueError: Invalid literal for Fraction: '1 / 2'
```

You could handle this by cleaning the string first.

This could be done with regex:

```
import fractions
import re

def clean(string, pattern=re.compile("\s")):
    return pattern.sub('', string)

def parse_rational(string):
    string = clean(string)
    try:
        return float(string)
    except ValueError:
        return float(fractions.Fraction(string))
```

or clean can even just be: `return ''.join(string.split())`

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) might help, if you specifically need to work with fractions. It will give you the ability to work with numerator, denominator and sign